# How can I have IS NULL condition in TypeORM find options?

Tags: sql, where-clause, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

In my queries I'm using TypeORM `find` option.
How can I have `IS NULL` condition in the `where` clause?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Another way is you can use `IsNull()` function, for example:

```js
import { IsNull } from "typeorm";
return await getRepository(User).findOne({
    where: { 
      username: IsNull()
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want the opposite (when looking for a non-null column). Wrap that method. `Not(IsNull())`

Answer (score 171):

If someone is looking for NOT NULL, it would be like this:

```js
import { IsNull, Not } from "typeorm";

return await getRepository(User).findOne({
    where: { 
      username: Not(IsNull())
    }
});
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use [QueryBuilder](http://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder) for this purpose:

```
const users = await userRepository.createQueryBuilder("user")
     .where("user.name IS NULL")
     .getMany();
```

Comment: That is the manual way of doing it, but if you see [this typeorm code](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/738/files#diff-7c493ff0fd61cba71965f521d80f04e0) it can do it for you - I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Maybe it helps somebody if you need not null values use: `.where("user.name IS NOT NULL")`

Comment: .where("user.name IS NOT NULL") is not working for me

Answer (score 5):

In addition to hungneox answer you should know that you have a lot of predefined operators.

This is from the file that defines it:

```
export declare type FindOperatorType = "not" | 
"lessThan" | 
"lessThanOrEqual" | 
"moreThan" | 
"moreThanOrEqual" | 
"equal" | 
"between" | 
"in" | 
"any" | 
"isNull" | 
"like" | 
"raw";
```

Each of the above can be set in the "Operator" part here:

```
{ 
  where: { 
    propertyToCheck: <Operator>
  }
}
```

You just import it from the @typeorm package and use it like a function e.g LessThan():

```
import { Repository, Between, IsNull, LessThan } from 'typeorm';

{ 
  where: { 
    age: LessThan(50)
  }
}
```

This is really strong and important tool to know if you want to master typeorm :)
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I really don't like to have to use the `QueryBuilder` from TypeORM for this as this should, in my opinion, be treated as expected when using `FindConditions`.

Unfortunately, with something like the following code:

```
async articleRequests(
  accepted?: ArticleRequestAcceptance,
): Promise<ArticleRequest[]> {
  const where: FindConditions<ArticleRequest>[] | FindConditions<ArticleRequest> = {};

  if (accepted !== undefined) {
    switch (accepted) {
      case ArticleRequestAcceptance.Accepted:
        where.accepted = true;
        break;
      case ArticleRequestAcceptance.Rejected:
        where.accepted = false;
        break;
      case ArticleRequestAcceptance.NotReviewedYet:
        where.accepted = undefined;
        break;
    }
  }

  return await ArticleRequest.find({ where }).catch(reason => {
    throw reason.message;
  });
}
```

TypeORM gets you a SQL query that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT '...' WHERE "ArticleRequest"."accepted" = NULL
```

because, as can be seen from TypeORM log output, `... WHERE "ArticleRequest"."accepted" = @0 -- PARAMETERS: [null]`, properties with `undefined` values (`accepted` in this case) get converted to `null`s inside the parameters array and then they are simply injected into the SQL string.

The SQL standard says that any comparison with `null` results in `null` so for comparison operators, like `=` or `<>`, in SQL this should make no sense, but the reasoning is that comparing to null means "unknown" so that why such queries don't return any results. If you ask me, SQL is broken here.

So yeah, as @hungneox said, the solution is to use `IsNull()` which returns a special `FindOperator` for that specific column you need to be queried as `IS NULL` and not `= NULL`.

Like this:

```
  if (accepted !== undefined) {
    switch (accepted) {
      case ArticleRequestAcceptance.Accepted:
        where.accepted = true;
        break;
      case ArticleRequestAcceptance.Rejected:
        where.accepted = false;
        break;
      case ArticleRequestAcceptance.NotReviewedYet:
        where.accepted = IsNull();
        break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TheModel.find({ theField: null })
```

will do as you'd expect.

Comment: Not necessarily, this can potentially cause a type error. You can also use `field: IsNull()`.