# Typeorm Find condition for related entity

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

I have two entities, a `User` and a `Post` entity. A user can have multiple posts.

I would like to find a post based on the post title and the name of the author like this:

```
const post = await postsRepository.find({
  where: {
    title: postTitle,
    user: {
      name: userName,
    },
  },
  relations: ['user'],
});
```

`Typeorm` generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT `Post`.`id` AS `Post_id`, `Post`.`title` AS `Post_title`, `Post`.`user_id`
AS `Post_user_id`, `Post__user`.`id` AS `Post__user_id`, `Post__user`.`name` AS
`Post__user_name` FROM `posts` `Post` LEFT JOIN `users` `Post__user` ON
`Post__user`.`id`=`Post`.`user_id` WHERE (`Post`.`user_id` = ?) -- PARAMETERS: [null]
```

As you can see, it is not querying the name attribute at all.

But it doesn't work and I can't find anything in the documentation.

[Edit]: On the other hand, the following code works as expected but isn't using joins to query the relation:

```
const user = await usersRepository.findOne({ name: userName });
const post = await postsRepository.find({
  where: {
    title: postTitle,
    user: {
      id: user.id,
    },
  },
  relations: ['user'],
});
```

[/Edit]

The only thing I could was something like this

```
const post = await postsRepository.createQueryBuilder('posts')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('posts.user', 'user')
  .where({
    title: postTitle,
  })
  .andWhere('user.name = :name', { name: userName })
  .getOne();
```

So this works but tbh it looks super shitty and is pretty annoying to write when you need to filter by additional relations.

Is there anything I have missed in the documentation?

Comment: Can you paste the SQL of the generated query for the first code bit you pasted? The issue looks easy to solve, doing so could save some time in trying to help you out.

Comment: @0xCAP The first code snippet generates the following SQL query: ```SELECT `Post`.`id` AS `Post_id`, `Post`.`title` AS `Post_title`, `Post`.`user_id` AS `Post_user_id`, `Post__user`.`id` AS `Post__user_id`, `Post__user`.`name` AS `Post__user_name` FROM `posts` `Post` LEFT JOIN `users` `Post__user` ON `Post__user`.`id`=`Post`.`user_id` WHERE (`Post`.`user_id` = ?) -- PARAMETERS: [null]```

Comment: @lenny.myr In SQL `Post.user_id = NULL` is always `false` (as it returns NULL). You want either sql to `Post.user_id IS NULL` (`IsNull()` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879840/how-can-i-have-is-null-condition-in-typeorm-find-options ) or using the MySql NULL-safe equal operator `<=>`